# Does Brother Malachi the Healer's blessing actually do anything?

Tags: diablo-iii

When you start the game and arrive in Tristram, Brother Malachi the Healer gives you a blessing if you talk to him. There's a little sound effect and a flash of light as he blesses you.

Does it actually do anything? I don't see any obvious effect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The blessing from Brother Malachi, as well as from other healers in other acts, simply completely heals you if you are wounded.